# Installing opencv on raspberry pi b+ using annaconda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to install `opencv` using annaconda into raspberry pi. I have tried -

```
conda install opencv

conda install -c menpo opencv
```

I have also tried using

```
conda search -t opencv
```

I changed the channel as well using -

```
conda install --channel https://conda.annaconda.org/poppy-project opencv3
```

> However, it adds `/linux-armv7l/` to the channel and gives the
>   following error message - Could not connect to
>   https://conda.annaconda.org/poppy-project/noarch/ .Could not connect
>   to https://conda.annaconda.org/poppy-project/linux-armv7l/ .....
>   Error: No packages found in current linux-armv7l channels matching:
>   opencv3
>
> You can search for this package on anaconda.org with
>
> ```
> anaconda search -t conda opencv3
> ```

I need to install for python 2.7

Could anyone please help me install this?

Comment: have  you tried with pip

Comment: There is a typo - it should be `conda.anaconda.org`, you have two `n`s in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by creating New environment with command:

```
conda create --name MyEnv python
```

After activating the environment by

```
source activate MyEnv
```

Then given following command

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/poppy-project opencv3
```

My issue resolved, hope it will help you!